# Ubuntu sound quality is lower than Windows

Tags: drivers, realtek

I got bored of Windows and installed Ubuntu. But I noticed something. Sound quality was better in Windows 11. I installed Easy Effects and applied the PerceftEQ Profile but it doesn't sound like windows. My motherboard has Realtek ALC-892 audio codec. Is it related to Realtek drivers? Is it possible to install them on Ubuntu?

Comment: Guys now I am using My Monitor's jack and my speaker sounds a little bit clear.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please type `inxi -Fxz` in a terminal and copy and paste the output into your question so we can get an overview of your system. If you don't have inxi, you can install it with `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install inxi`.